# Transform simple map to Map of list of map

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` and I need to transform it to `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>` using lambda. Using a normal for loop this problem is trivial but I want to tackle it using java8 lambdas.

The `categoryToSubCat` is of type `<String, List<String>>`.

Using for loops this is the transformation:

```
final Map < String, List < Map < String, String >>> transformedMap = new HashMap < > ();
for (Map.Entry < String, List < String >> entry: categoryToSubCat.entrySet()) {
    final List < Map < String, String >> subCats = new ArrayList < > ();
    for (String subCat: entry.getValue()) {
        final Map < String, String > data = new HashMap < > ();
        data.put("text", subCat);
        data.put("value", subCat);
        subCats.add(data);
    }
    transformedMap.put(entry.getKey(), subCats);
}
```

The initial map contains data like:

```
{
  "CAT1": [
    "CAT1-A",
    "CAT1-B"
  ],
  "CAT2": [
    "CAT2-A",
    "CAT2-B",
    "CAT2-C"
  ]
}
```

After the transformation it should become something like

```
{
  "CAT1": [
    {
      "text": "CAT1-A",
      "value": "CAT1-A"
    },
    {
      "text": "CAT1-B",
      "value": "CAT1-B"
    }
  ],
  "CAT2": [
    {
      "text": "CAT2-A",
      "value": "CAT2-A"
    },
    {
      "text": "CAT2-B",
      "value": "CAT2-B"
    },
    {
      "text": "CAT2-C",
      "value": "CAT2-C"
    }
  ]
}
```

This does not seem like a problem which cannot be solved using lambdas but I'm just able to get how to do about it.

Please suggest a better approach than the for loop.

Comment: "Please suggest a better approach than the for loop." - Better in what way? What's the problem with that loop?

Comment: Using this structure is really ugly, I suggest to use classes to represent your data instead of lists and maps

Comment: @YCF_L I agree with you but there are some cases where using classes complicstes the code unnecessary. I haven't mentioned in this but I need to send a json to downstream so a classes would be just an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Though an ideal suggestion would be to not use such a data structure, yet if you were to transform the given input, you could try something like:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> transformedMap = categoryToSubCat.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .map(subCat -> Map.of("text", subCat, "value", subCat))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()), (a, b) -> b));
```

Comment: @Nikolas Well at first I misunderstood the question as grouping by `key`, then realized the `text` and `value` as keys in the Map of `List` and reattempted.

Comment: Aside: The `map` operation of stream, could be changed to `.map(subCat -> {
                                    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                                    data.put("text", subCat);
                                    data.put("value", subCat);
                                    return data;
                                })` for Java-8 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lambda version code.

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> transformedMap = categoryToSubCat.keySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        //keyMapper
                        key -> key,
                        //valueMapper
                        key -> categoryToSubCat.get(key).stream().map(listStr -> {
                                    Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<>();
                                    map.put("text", listStr);
                                    map.put("value", listStr);
                                    return map;
                                }
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList())
                ));
```

or

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> transformedMap = categoryToSubCat.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        //keyMapper
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        //valueMapper
                        entrySet -> entrySet.getValue().stream().map(listStr -> {
                                    Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<>();
                                    map.put("text", listStr);
                                    map.put("value", listStr);
                                    return map;
                                }
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList())
                ));
```